# is it possible to set a View as wallpaper on home screen in android?

Tags: android

my question is that I am creating a custom analog clock by extending View, I want to display this clock on home screen as a wallpaper. Can anybody know the answer..any suggestions are appreciated...thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only draw the analog clock in a live wallpaper and use that as the background. You can not just set a view as a wallpaper.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply.